# "call" instruction that seemingly jumps into itself

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, g++

I have some C++ code

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

class A {
public:
    void do_it() { std::printf("aaa"); }
};

void
call_it(const boost::function<void()> &f)
{
    f();
}

void
func()
{
    A *a = new A;
    call_it(boost::bind(&A::do_it, a));
}
```

which gcc 4 compiles into the following assembly (from `objdump`):

```
00000030 <func()>:
  30:   55                      push   %ebp
  31:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
  33:   56                      push   %esi
  34:   31 f6                   xor    %esi,%esi
  36:   53                      push   %ebx
  37:   bb 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ebx
  3c:   83 ec 40                sub    $0x40,%esp
  3f:   c7 04 24 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,(%esp)
  46:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   47 <func()+0x17>
  4b:   8d 55 ec                lea    0xffffffec(%ebp),%edx
  4e:   89 14 24                mov    %edx,(%esp)
  51:   89 5c 24 04             mov    %ebx,0x4(%esp)
  55:   89 74 24 08             mov    %esi,0x8(%esp)
  59:   89 44 24 0c             mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
  ; the rest of the function is omitted
```

I can't understand the operand of `call` instruction here, why does it call into itself, but with one byte off?

Comment: May we see the C++ code as well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The call is probably to an external function, and the address you see (FFFFFFFC) is just a placeholder for the real address, which the linker and/or loader will take care of later.

Comment: Yeah this is the correct answer.  You'll see tons of these if you objdump an unlinked .o file.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I, indeed, was objdumping an *.o file.